# Laravel 8 Login JWT Auth always 401

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt, token

I am using 'tymon/jwt-auth' in Laravel 8. I followed the steps exactly as on 'https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/laravel-installation/', but I still always get 401 Unauthorized.

I cannot figure out the cause of it while debugging in Postman and I am not doing anything different than what the guy in the tutorial was doing. I looked up online and some suspect it could be that the password is not read as an encrypted string (md5). Any thoughts?

```js
AuthController.php:

        public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (! $token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Email or Password invalid'], 401);
        }
        return $this->respondWithToken($token);

    }
 
 Inside User Model:

    <?php
    
    namespace App;
    
    use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
    
    class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
    {
        use Notifiable;
    
        // Rest omitted for brevity
    
        /**
         * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
         *
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getJWTIdentifier()
        {
            return $this->getKey();
        }
    
        /**
         * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function getJWTCustomClaims()
        {
            return [];
        }
    }

  config/auth.php:

        'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
        ],

        'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

 router/api.php:

        Route::group([
    
        'middleware' => 'api',
        'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
        'prefix' => 'auth'
    
        ], function ($router) {
    
          Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
          Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
          Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
          Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');
    
        });
```

Comment: the password wouldn't be saved in md5 ... did you hash the password when you created this User record? are you passing the plain text version to the login?

Comment: I created an user in phpmyadmin with a md5 password for testing. So the password is hashed. In Postman body I am passing two keys: the email and the password of the earlier created user

Comment: laravel doesn't use md5, it uses bcrypt, so that won't work with the user provider, it has to be bcrypt by default ... md5 is not used for passwords any more btw, it is insecure

Comment: So what should I change in my code in order to make this jwt auth work?

Comment: hash the password using bcrypt in the database ...

Comment: You're right. Thank you. I had to change the type of the password from md5 to bcrypt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use bcrypt format in the password field instead of md5.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).